# How can I parse and filter out unique names in a substring from within an array?

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic

I have a string array that contains names, such as the following (in psuedocode):

```
string nameArray[7]
nameArray[0] = "JohnJacob"
nameArray[1] = "George"
nameArray[2] = "JacobBill"
nameArray[3] = "GeorgeBill"
nameArray[4] = "PatZach"
nameArray[5] = "BobJacob"
nameArray[6] = "MichaelScottChristine"
```

I would like to make it so that this array does not have a name that appears more than once, even has a substring. It's fine if two names are stuck together; just so long as neither of the substrings are found in any other element of the array. One potential result might look like this:

```
nameArrayUpdated[0] = "John"
nameArrayUpdated[1] = "Jacob"
nameArrayUpdated[2] = "George"
nameArrayUpdated[3] = "Bill"
nameArrayUpdated[4] = "PatZach"
nameArrayUpdated[5] = "Bob"
nameArrayUpdated[6] = "MichaelScottChristine"
```

My initial approach was to iterate through the array, and check if any element was a substring of another element, and then remove said substring. Something like this (again, pseudocode):

```
for (i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
{
   str tmp = nameArray[i];
   for (j = 0; j < arrLength; j++)
   {
      if (i != j)
      {
         if (nameArray[j].ContainsSubstring(tmp) == true)
            nameArray[j].RemoveSubstring(tmp)
      }

   }
}
```

But this is problematic for several reasons. One, it would require an unknown amount of iterations to go through the array. For example, "JohnJacob" would not be separated on the first iteration, but would upon a second iteration. Secondly, strings like "JacobBill" and "BobJacob" would be considered unique in and of themselves, and not substrings of anything else...despite that Jacob is contained in both of these strings.

Is there any practical way to separate out these names?

Comment: This is not strictly a VBA code. So the best to do is to add the [Arrays] tag to the question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! I've removed the VBA tag and added the arrays and language-agnostic tags. I appreciate your helpful feedback!

Comment: I have in mind a VBA solution, but I would like you to confirm that the way I understand your question is correct, respectively: 1. A "name" is a string starting with an `UpperCase` letter. 2. A larger array should be obtained by splitting the shown one in above defined "Names". 3. If a string in original array is **not found, or found only once in the larger array**, it must be used as it is (George, PatZach, MichaelScottChristine). 4. The final array to be composed from unique names from the larger array plus not split ones, but also checked to not have duplicates in larger array ("George").

Comment: Is the above explained understanding correct?

Comment: are you only interested in substrings that start with a capital letter or would you also consider `obBill` as a duplicate string (eg, `BobBill` and `JacobBilly`)? if a substring shows up in more than one array element how do you determine precedence (by array index? alphabetic ordering of the entire array element? something else?)? what to do if an array element's substrings have already been selected/used (eg, `nameArrayUpdated[7] = "JohnGeorge"`) or is a duplicate (eg, `nameArrayUpdated[8] = "JohnJacob") ... in other words all substrings of the array element occur in 3+ array elements?

Comment: is there a relationship between `nameArray[N]` and `nameArrayUpdated[N]`? if 'yes', then why/how does `George` move from N=1 to N=2? or is there no relationship between the 2 arrays and `nameArrayUpdated[]` is actually a new array of unique names/substrings? (or is there a typo in the question?)

Answer (score 0):

You did not answer my clarification question...

Please, copy the next code in an Excel standard module and run the first `Sub` (`extractNamesArr`). The code assumes that my understanding expressed in my comment is correct:

```
Sub extractNamesArr()
  Dim arrN, arrFin, arr, mtch, strRepl As String, i As Long, j As Long, boolNot As Boolean
  arrN = Split("JohnJacob,George,JacobBill,GeorgeBill,PatZach,BobJacob,MichaelScottChristine", ",")
  
  arr = extractNB(arrN) 'create an array of twp dictionaries
                                        '1. above array elements (as keys) and all extracted names (as item) per each key
                                        '2. all unique extracted names, as dictionary keys
  Debug.Print Join(arr(0).Keys, "|") ' just to visually see the dictionary keys
  arrFin = arr(1).Keys               'place in an array the unique extracted names
  
  Dim key, k
  For Each key In arr(0).Keys        'iterate between the dictionary keys
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr(0)(key))
            For Each k In arr(0).Keys
                If key <> k Then
                    If InStr(1, k, arr(0)(key)(i), vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
                        boolNot = True: Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
            If boolNot Then Exit For
        Next i
        If Not boolNot Then 'none of the names belonging to the respective kay, NOT FOUND
            For j = 0 To UBound(arr(0)(key))
                mtch = Application.match(arr(0)(key)(j), arrFin, 0)
                If j = UBound(arr(0)(key)) Then
                      arrFin(mtch - 1) = key
                Else
                    strRepl = arrFin(mtch - 1) & "@#$%": arrFin(mtch - 1) = strRepl
                    arrFin = filter(arrFin, strRepl, False)
                End If
            Next j
        End If
        boolNot = False
  Next key

  Debug.Print Join(arrFin, "|") 'just to see the final returned array (unique names)
End Sub

Function extractNB(arr) As Variant
   Dim arrInt, k As Long, El, i As Long, frstEl As Long
   Dim dict As Object, dict1 As Object
   
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  'dictionary to keep all initial composed array elements (as key) and its split names (as item)
   Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'dictionary to keep UNIQUE  extracted names
   
   frstEl = 1                     'first letter to build the first name string
   For Each El In arr             'iterate between the array elements
        ReDim arrInt(Len(El))     'ReDim the intermediary array to the string number of digits
        For i = 2 To Len(El)      'iterate between string characters, starting from the second one:
            If isUpper(Mid(El, i, 1)) Then                        'if the character is Upper case:
               arrInt(k) = Mid(El, frstEl, i - frstEl): k = k + 1 'place the Name inthe intermediary dictionary item array
               dict1(arrInt(k - 1)) = vbNullString                'load the dictionary to keep all UNIQUE extracted names
               frstEl = i          'adapt the first character number, to extract the next name
            End If
        Next i
        If frstEl < i - 1 Then     'extract the last name:
            arrInt(k) = Mid(El, frstEl, Len(El) - frstEl + 1): k = k + 1
            dict1(arrInt(k - 1)) = vbNullString                           'load the dictionary keeping all UNIQUE extracted names
        End If
        ReDim Preserve arrInt(k - 1)    'keep only the loaded array elements
        dict.Add El, arrInt             'create the dictionary key and its array item
        frstEl = 1: Erase arrInt: k = 0 'reinitialize the necessary variables
   Next

   extractNB = Array(dict, dict1)  'return an array containing the two dictionaries
End Function

Function isUpper(mstr As String) As Boolean 'Check if the  character is Upper case
    Select Case Asc(mstr)
            Case 65 To 90
                isUpper = True
            Case 97 To 122
                isUpper = False
            Case Else
                isUpper = False
    End Select
End Function
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it. If something unclear, do  not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

I tried commenting all code lines which could not be easily understood...